# Entity Framework search multiple words

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I want to create a search query with Entity Framework (EF6) . To better understand I will explain with example.

I have 5 words(string).

1. "My name is jack"
2. "My age is 35 years old"
3. "My job is developper"
4. "what is your name"
5. "China's population is over 1 billion"

Now i want to create an EF query search that having the following results:

- When search is `My name` the results are numbers 1 and 2 and 3 and 4
- When search is `is` the results are numbers 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5

This is my query:

```
var query = (from q1 in _db.QuestionTbl where q1.questionTitle.Any(a => q1.questionTitle.Contains("search")) select q1).ToList();
```

But i can`t get correct answer.

Comment: you need to change "search" string with your search variable

Comment: @jonaChaz No, unfortunately, this was not a good tip

Comment: try this : var query = _db.QuestionTb1.Where(a => a.questionTitle.Contains(MyVariable)).ToList();

Comment: @jonaChaz Did you know the question exactly?

Comment: its true if it contains only one of the words? its that want you want?

Comment: @jonaChaz When search string is `My name`, i want all strings contains `My` , `name` and `My name`

Comment: @topcool but when the search is 'is', you want to not return 4 which contains the word 'is'? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @pep Oh, I corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@jonaChaz's answer works, but is inefficient in one important way: it will produce 1 round-trip query to SQL for each term in the search. If you write it this way instead, EntityFramework compiles it into a single query / round trip to the server and can save significant overhead, especially for multi-term searches:

```
    string search = "My name";
    var terms = search.Split(' ');
    var results = _db.QuestionTb1
        .Where(q => terms.Any(term => q.questionTitle.Contains(term)))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in EF Core, or am I missing something?

Comment: doesn't work for me either in EF Core 5

Answer (score 2):

```
    string search = "My is";
    var arr = search.Split(' ');

    List<QuestionTb1> query = new List<QuestionTb1>();
    foreach (var word in arr)
    {
        var newQuestionTb1s = _db.QuestionTb1.Where(a => a.questionTitle.Contains(word)).Except(query).ToList();
        query.AddRange(newQuestionTb1s);
    }
```

this code splits the search text by 'Words'(spaces) and then get the questions with the searchtext word by word.

Comment: what is `MyVariable` ?

Comment: its word sorry i forgot to change

Comment: works but i think each loop is a query you can do this is one query fyi